# How to filter MYSQL database table by current date

Tags: mysql

My table:

```
id message     sent_user_id sent_user_name received_user_id received_user_name table_no message_time        status
 1 Need a help            6 Saman kumara                 11 Kamal Perera              0 2016-12-07 17:28:41      0
 2 Need a help            6 Saman kumara                 10 Nimal Rajapaksha          0 2017-01-05 18:17:35      0
 3 Need a help            6 Saman kumara                 10 Nimal Rajapaksha          0 2017-01-05 18:21:20      0
 4 Need a help            6 Saman kumara                 10 Nimal Rajapaksha          0 2017-01-05 18:22:15      1
```

I need to select all rows where message_time equals to current date.

```
SELECT * FROM message_info WHERE message_time = CURDATE();
```

This is query I tried. But it does not work.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: You wouldn't normally store sent_user_name, and received_user_name in such a table.

Comment: I tried it. This is query which i tried. "SELECT * FROM message_info WHERE message_time = CURDATE();" but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM message_info WHERE DATE_FORMAT(message_time, "%y-%m-%d")  = CURDATE();
```

You want to compare the `dates`, so you have to remove the time data from the `datetime` in your table. You can do this by using `DATE_FORMAT()`.

If there is an `index` on the column `message_time` you should use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM message_info 
WHERE message_time 
    BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%y-%m-%d 00:00:00") AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "23-59-59")
```

When you use a function to change the value of your column its `index` can not be used. By changing the search algorithm to look for dates between `beginning of day x` and `end of day x` you are getting the same result without having to change the value for the search.